# How to append result from ajax using ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I'm building simple ruby on rails app and faced with a problem using coffiescript and ajax:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_comment").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
     $("#new_comment").append xhr.responseText
```

I couldn't take values from xhr.responseText but it add all the json to div and also got error and console

```
 Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined
```

In controller I answered like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :newComment => comment_params } }
```

Please Help me with this issue.

Comment: Try data.responseText

Comment: the same result and could not add nothing

Comment: What do you expect `responseText` to be?

Comment: @Pavan I want it like object  which I could use like responseText.newComment. and append value

Comment: From the controller you are only sending `success` and `newComment` in the json. Try `data.newComment` and see is that what you want

Comment: @Pavan Cannot read property 'newComment' of undefined

Comment: Try changing it to `$("#new_comment").on("ajax:success", (e, data, newComment, status, xhr) ->` and use `$("#new_comment").append newComment`

Comment: @Pavan newComment empty